# How can I use this React library with React-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, npm, reactjs, react-rails

I came upon this:

https://github.com/ssorallen/turbo-react

And I like what it does, I am just a bit confused about how I use this code within my Rails project that currently uses the [React-Rails gem](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails)

I am mostly confused about where to put the code so that I can read it into my Rails gem with React Rails. If I paste the main JS file into my vendor/assets folder, I get this message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
```

I know that I am just fundamentally misunderstanding how to include this kind of JS file into my Rails project.

Comment: What specifically confuses you?

Comment: I'm wondering where I put the js file in order to use them properly. I can't just add them to vendor assets because they rely on globals and require statements that are not recognized.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain your confusion.  There's not enough there for someone to know how to help.

Comment: Sorry, made it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[src/turbo-react.js](https://github.com/ssorallen/turbo-react/blob/master/src/turbo-react.js) is meant for a Node.js environment, not a browser environment. I see another file, [public/dist/turbo-react.min.js](https://github.com/ssorallen/turbo-react/blob/master/public/dist/turbo-react.min.js), which has been "compiled" to run in a browser (using Webpack). You should copy that file into `vendor/assets`, then require it in `application.js`.

The first few lines of `src/turbo-react.js` gave me some signals that it is for Node.js:

```
if (global.Turbolinks === undefined) {
  throw "Missing Turbolinks dependency. TurboReact requires Turbolinks be included before it.";
}

var HTMLtoJSX = require("htmltojsx");
var JSXTransformer = require("react-tools");
var React = require("react");
```

`global` and `require` are both Node.js concepts which don't exist in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for this one I guess: https://github.com/ssorallen/turbo_react-rails

Installation instructions:

1. Add this line to your application's Gemfile:

   `gem 'turbo_react-rails'`
2. Install the updated gems

   `$ bundle install`
3. Require turbo-react in a JavaScript file like "application.js" after Turbolinks:

   `//= turbolinks
   //= require turbo-react`

That's it. Now if you click any link in your Web-Application it should be loaded via Ajax and use React to replace the tags in your page.